# Comparing arrays with sql

Tags: sql, arrays, comparison

I want to perform a 'SELECT' statement with a byte array (binary) parameter as a condition.
I tried to google it, but didn't find anything useful.

In general, I keep information of files in the database. one of the properties is the file's hash (binary).

I want to give a hash to the SELECT statement, and get all rows with the same hash value.

Comment: can you post the code you are trying to run? And tell us what SQL database you are using.

Comment: I'm using sql server ce 3.1. I want something like: Select * from BL_FILES where HASH = [byte array]
Currently i'm retrieving all files and performing the comparison using my code, but I want to implement a more elegant solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @PARA BINARY
SET @PARA = 0X000
SELECT @PARA
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    [Table]
WHERE
    PARA = @PARA
```

Comment: Is there's anyway for doing this without 'DECLARE'? i'm using SqlServerCe which only allows one statement per command

Comment: Thanks, I solved it using: "SELECT * FROM BL_FILES WHERE Hash = 0x + BitConverter.ToString(byte[]).Replace("-",string.Empty)